# cant figure out null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

okay, so ive been trying to find a solution to this for hours but i cant find one.
Heres me code that the log cat has said the null pointer expection is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class splash extends Activity{
Button begin;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    begin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    begin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent startmenu=new Intent("com.life.project.menu");
            startActivity(startmenu);
        }
    });
}

}
```

and heres the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/icon3">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="You have 20 minutes to increase your status as much as possible." />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Begin!"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:typeface="monospace" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

so when i try to run this it gets a null pointer exception and i dont know whats wrong with it, any ideas?

Comment: What line is the Null Pointer happening at?

Comment: Post the stack trace from the exception, please.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `setContentView` before `findViewById`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.the_layout_xml_name);
begin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
// ...
```